# Need help registering and setting up listener for local Oracle 19c database so I can connect sqldeveloper remotely

Tags: sql, oracle19c, tnsnames

Could someone help me.  I have a local 19c database running on Oracle Enterprise Linux 8.3. There's a pdb i created named orclpdb1 that i used to be able to connect to. At this point i didn't setup the listener to stay persistent and now all i can remotely connect to is the the cdb.

Here is some output from some of the commands and tnsnames.ora and listener.ora.  I'm new to this and the tnsnames.ora and listener.ora confuse the heck out of me with regards to services, listeners, and registries.

```
SQL> show parameter instance_name
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
instance_name                        string      ORCLCDB*

*SQL> show parameter local_listener
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
local_listener                       string      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=1
                                                 92.168.1.235)(PORT=1522))*

*SQL> show pdbs
    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 ORCLPDB1                       MOUNTED*

    [oracle@localhost admin]$ more listener.ora
    # listener.ora Network Configuration File: /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
    # Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
    PDB_LISTENER =
            (DESCRIPTION =
              (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.235)(PORT=1521))
             )
    SID_LIST_LISTENER_PDB1 =
      (SID_LIST =
          (SID_DESC =
            (GLOBAL_DBNAME = ORCLPDB1)
            (SID_NAME = ORCL)
            (ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1)
          )
      )
    LISTENER =
      (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
        (DESCRIPTION =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
        )
      )

    [oracle@localhost admin]$ more tnsnames.ora
    # tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
    # Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
    ORCLCDB =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SERVER = DEDICATED)
          (SERVICE_NAME = ORCLCDB)
        )
      )
    ORCLPDB1 =
       (DESCRIPTION =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.235)(PORT = 1521))
          (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SERVER = DEDICATED)
            (SERVICE_NAME=ORCLCDB)
    )
    )
    [oracle@localhost admin]$
```

Comment: Why different port numbers. 1522 in show parameter and 1521 in *.ora files. ?.what's the output of `lsnrctl status` and orcldpdb1 is in mounted state.Service name for `ORCLPDB1` in `tnsnames.ora` should be `ORCLPDB1`

Comment: Hi Suresh, Thats a good question.  I think i can change the local listener to 1521.  I made the service name orclcdb cause when i go into the pdb in sql the service_name parameter is listed as orclcdb.  I changed it in the tnsnames.ora and i changed the local_listener to 1521.  I am still getting an error.  I will post the lsnrctl status below.

Comment: ]$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 21-APR-2021 08:44:10

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 2: No such file or directory

Comment: suresh, i was able to resolve this.  I found an oracle document that recommended i place the ip address of my host into my /etc/hosts file.  once i did this all my listeners started and now i can connect.  Thank you for the help.